# How to stop the timer from speeding up when i click one of the buttons in javascript within html?

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

Im trying to make a slideshow of images that changes every 10 seconds but has a button at the bottom where if you clicked on the dot it will take you back to that image. The problem is when I click the of the buttons it speeds the timer up. how do i stop this, so that when i click on the button it resets the timer?

```
function showSlides() {
    var nextSlide = false
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 10000, slideIndex++); // Change image every 10 seconds
}
```

Comment: Assign the timer to an outer scope variable to get its ID, and [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout)  the current timeout before calling a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to a comment by Teemu. who showed me how to do it, i applyed it to the code and it works

```js
function timer() {
 this.STimer = setTimeout(showSlides, 10000, slideIndex++);
}

function cancelTimer(){
 clearTimeout(this.STimer);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
 cancelTimer();
 showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides() {
 var nextSlide = false
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
 timer();
}
```